# Run a query on Dynamic Table Name

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am getting my table names from a query, and i am trying to run a query on this table. Following is my code,

```
select count(COLUMN_NAME) from TABLE_NAME 
        where (TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_NAME) in 
        (SELECT TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_NAME 
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
        WHERE COLUMN_NAME IN ('hststr_batch_no','hstdt_expiry_date','hstdt_manuf_date')
        group by TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_NAME )
```

I tried linking them through many operators but none of them seem to work. How can i get this.

UPDATED:

I was trying to get the data in following format from my database structure.

```
Table Name    Column Name      No of rows in that column in that table
tab_1         batch_no         46
tab_1         mfg_date         46
tab_2         mfg_date         30
```

Currently I succeeded in getting the table names containing the columns i wanted using following query,

```
-- For tables having all three columns
SELECT TABLE_NAME 
      FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
      WHERE COLUMN_NAME IN ('hststr_batch_no','hstdt_expiry_date','hstdt_manuf_date')
group by TABLE_NAME
having count(distinct COLUMN_NAME) = 3  

-- For tables against columns
SELECT TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_NAME 
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
        WHERE COLUMN_NAME IN ('hststr_batch_no','hstdt_expiry_date','hstdt_manuf_date')
        group by TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_NAME
```

Now when i try to get something that i really want, i.e. number of rows in a given column in a given table i am getting error of unknown table name. That is because SQL is not accepting dynamic Table name. Help.

```
with data as (SELECT TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_NAME 
      FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
      WHERE COLUMN_NAME IN ('hststr_batch_no','hstdt_expiry_date','hstdt_manuf_date') )
select table_name, column_name, (select count(*) from table_name) as num from data
```

Comment: My bad, Kindly see the updated query.

Comment: you could cast values to an array like "select count(COLUMN_NAME) from TABLE_NAME 
        where array[TABLE_NAME::text,COLUMN_NAME::text] in 
        (SELECT array[TABLE_NAME::text,COLUMN_NAME::text]
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
        WHERE COLUMN_NAME IN ('hststr_batch_no','hstdt_expiry_date','hstdt_manuf_date')
        group by TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_NAME )"  but that would be slow

Comment: @LongBeard_Boldy Thanks for your reply, It returned the same error `Error : relation "table_name" does not exist Position: 32`. I was doing a bit of reading on Dynamic SQL http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html

Comment: do you actually have such a table named "table_name"? what is it you want to accomplish?

Comment: if you want to count columns per table , you dont need a subquery, just a simple query using grouping or windowed function like this one  "with data as (SELECT TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_NAME 
      FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
     WHERE COLUMN_NAME IN ('hststr_batch_no','hstdt_expiry_date','hstdt_manuf_date'))
select table_name, column_name, count(*) over(partition by table_name)   from data"

Comment: @LongBeard_Boldy I dont actually have any table named `table_name`. `table_name` is my output from another query stored in table `data`.

Comment: @unkn0wn are you trying to get list of tables with some columns and the number of such tables in one result?..

Comment: @VaoTsun Kindly see the updated question.

Comment: @VaoTsun: please do not add the `[database]` tag to questions that are already tagged with a specific DBMS product. See [the tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/database/info): "*If it is about a particular database management system, please use that tag instead*"

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yes - just checked the description and found that "please use that tag instead" - sorry. I actually marked two more before idea I'm tagging wrong came to my mind - I'll try to find and fix it. sorry for the mess - I created it willing to make some order :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are ok with approximation, join data against pg_stat_... statistics, eg:

```
t=# select schemaname,relname,n_live_tup,column_name 
from pg_stat_user_tables t 
join information_schema.columns c on c.table_name = relname and c.table_schema = schemaname 
where column_name in ('starttime','i');
 schemaname | relname | n_live_tup | column_name
------------+---------+------------+-------------
 public     | intern  |          0 | starttime
 public     | bi      |          4 | i
 public     | i       |          2 | i
 public     | c       |         20 | starttime
 public     | s2      |          2 | i
(5 rows)
```

if you want exact count (which btw can be obsolete, by the time you are parsing the result, so is not that precious), you need some dynamic sql, eg:

```
t=# do
$$
declare
 _r record;
 _t text;
begin
 for _r in (select c.table_schema,c.table_name, c.column_name from information_schema.columns c where column_name in ('starttime','i')) loop
  execute format ($f$select %L||' '||count(1) from %I.%I$f$,_r.table_schema||' '|| _r.table_name,_r.table_schema, _r.table_name) into _t;
  raise info '%',_t;
 end loop;
end;
$$
;
INFO:  public intern 20
INFO:  public bi 4
INFO:  public i 2
INFO:  public c 20
INFO:  public s2 2
DO
Time: 32.743 ms
```

btw in my data sample you see that live count gave different results for one table "intern" 20 against 0. Well, I should have first analyze it:

```
t=# analyze verbose public.intern;
INFO:  analyzing "public.intern"
INFO:  "intern": scanned 1 of 1 pages, containing 20 live rows and 20 dead rows; 20 rows in sample, 20 estimated total rows
ANALYZE
Time: 64.210 ms
```

Now approximation will give same result as dynamic sql:

```
t=# select schemaname,relname,n_live_tup,column_name
t-#     from pg_stat_user_tables t
t-#     join information_schema.columns c on c.table_name = relname and c.table_schema = schemaname
t-#     where column_name in ('starttime','i');
 schemaname | relname | n_live_tup | column_name
------------+---------+------------+-------------
 public     | intern  |         20 | starttime
 public     | bi      |          4 | i
 public     | i       |          2 | i
 public     | c       |         20 | starttime
 public     | s2      |          2 | i
(5 rows)
```

Comment: Thanks alot, that's what i needed.